# Start an interactive bash prompt in Kubernetes with custom pod options

Tags: kubernetes, interactive

I can start an "interactive pod" using:

```sh
$ kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --tty --image ubuntu -- bash
```

How can I add a [customized hosts file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/) for this pod?

That is, one or more entries in `hostAliases` which is defined in the pod manifest.

One option is to create a pod that runs some idle process:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-shell
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "8.8.8.8"
    hostnames:
    - "dns.google"
  containers:
  - name: my-shell
    image: ubuntu
    command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo The app is running! && sleep 3600']
```

Applying that using `kubectl apply` and then `kubectl exec` into the running pod.

Is it possible to more directly start an interactive pod with a specific pod spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `--overrides='{ "spec": { "hostAliases": [ { "ip": "8.8.8.8", "hostnames": [ "dns.google" ] } ] } }'` to the `kubectl run` command:

```
kubectl run my-shell --rm -i --tty --image ubuntu --overrides='{ "spec": { "hostAliases": [ { "ip": "8.8.8.8", "hostnames": [ "dns.google" ] } ] } }' -- bash
```

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run